# Determine which index of an array property is being set using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, indexing

I am creating an OPC client whereby one can read tags of an electrical device.  This is done by setting up items in an OPC group.  I want a property that is an array of bool[] to set items as active or inactive.  I need to know which index of this property bool[] was used to set the property so I can use that to activate the item.  I could just use a method but would prefer a property.  _theGroup is the OPC group which holds the items.

```
private bool[] _ItemActive;    
public bool[] itemActive {
    get { return _ItemActive; }
    set {
        if (_theGroup != null) {
            int itemIndex = ?? // I don't know how to find property index access by user
            int itemHandle = itemHandles[itemIndex]; //uses index to discover handle
            _theGroup.SetActiveState(itemHandle, value, out err); // use handle to set item active
        }
        _ItemActive = value;
    }
}
```

The user would do something like this.

```
opcClient.itemActive[3] = false;
```

I need to be able to discover the 3 and plug it into itemIndex shown above in my setter of my array of bool[]

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom collection with overriden indexer operator, where you would do your custom logic. But creating a setter method `SetItemActivation(int,bool)` seems to be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I need to be able to set the active state both before and after the class is instantiated.  The first _theGroup would be null so it would just set the property.  Then when the _theGroup is started it uses this property to determine if they should start out active or not.  Then after _theGroup is running and not null I have to activate it with that SetActiveState method of the group.  So I was trying to get a property to do do both.  But I agree a setter method would be cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: create a new class whose instances track changes to their entries; whenever an index value is changed, then an event is fired telling which entry was changed and to what value.  Here is such a class (Of course the code below could use generics to replace bools to be more versatile):

```
// This class tracks changes to its entries
public class BoolArray_Tracked{
  // Set up the data for which changes at specific indices must be tracked
  private bool[] _trackedBools;
  public bool this[int itemIndex]{
    get { return _trackedBools[itemIndex]; }
    set {
      // check if something really changed
      // not sure if you want this
      if(_trackedBools[itemIndex] != value){
      _trackedBools[itemIndex] = value;
      OnIndexChanged(itemIndex, value);// Raise an event for changing the data
      }
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  public BoolArray_Tracked(bool[] _trackedBools){
    this._trackedBools = _trackedBools;
  }

  // Set up the event raiser
  public delegate void IndexEventHandler(object sender, IndexEventArgs a);
  public event IndexEventHandler RaiseIndexEvent;

  // Raise an event for changing the data
  private void OnIndexChanged(int indexNumber, bool boolValue){
    if (RaiseIndexEvent != null)
      RaiseIndexEvent(this, new IndexEventArgs(indexNumber, boolValue));
  }
}

// This is class enables events with integer and boolean fields
public class IndexEventArgs : EventArgs{
  public int Index{get; private set;}
  public bool Value{get; private set;}

  public IndexEventArgs(int _index, bool _value){
    Index = _index;
    Value = _value;
  }
}
```

Next implement the OPC class:

```
class OPC_client{
  // Tracked bool array
  public BoolArray_Tracked ItemActive{get; set;}

  // Constructor
  public OPC_client(bool[] boolItemActive){
    ItemActive = new BoolArray_Tracked(boolItemActive);
    ItemActive.RaiseIndexEvent += Handle_ItemActive_IndexChange;
  }

  // State what should happen when an item changes
  private void Handle_ItemActive_IndexChange(object sender, IndexEventArgs e){
    //if (_theGroup != null) {//Your code in the question
      int itemIndex = e.Index; 
      //int itemHandle = itemHandles[itemIndex]; //Your code
      //_theGroup.SetActiveState(itemHandle, value, out err); // Yours
    //} //Your code

    Console.WriteLine("The array `ItemActive' was changed"
      + " at entry " + itemIndex.ToString() 
      + " to value " + e.Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Finally implement a simple program that tests this

```
static void Main(string[] args){
  OPC_client opcTest = new OPC_client(new bool[]{true, false});
  Console.WriteLine("Testing if message appears if value stays the same");
  opcTest.ItemActive[0] = true;

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Testing if message appears if value changes");
  opcTest.ItemActive[0] = false;
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```